# Retrieve text (Twitter) from command line in Linux

Tags: linux, twitter, rss, publish-subscribe

I have the following strange requirement: A given free proprietary software can be downloaded via a temporal link, which is valid for one day. This URL is used in a script (TravisCI / Docker) to download this product and install it. However, after one day, if the script is used again, the URL is invalid, and the script fails.

I would like to have a way to get that a valid URL and use a new one. It is not possible to get the new new URL directly from the website.

I was thinking about publishing a valid link in a public place, such as Twitter with a specific hashtag, and retrieve the link by querying the hashtag in Twitter. Any user that wants to use the scripts (TravisCI / Docker) just publish a new valid link, and the scripts will use it to download the software.

However, it is not possible to search in Twitter.

Is there any way to query Twitter without authentication from Command line in Linux?
What other method do you think I can use to retrieve a text (the valid URL) from Command Line in Linux? The important is that one person shares the valid link, and other persons using the script can use the valid link.

This is the project where I need that feature: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/angoca/db2-install/dockerfile/

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://tieba.baidu.com, where you can post anythng in a specific topic.  Find a topic that no one cares and post anything you like there. Then you can just retrieve the latest post.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I want, but the site is in Chinese, and I do not even found the option to change the language. Do you have any documentation about posting and searching there?

Comment: http://tieba.baidu.com/f?ie=utf-8&kw=noonecares&fr=search
This link brings you to the "noonecares" topic.
You can enter any string in the search bar. It's really easy to find a empty place if your string doesn't make any sense.
But to post, you will have to get a account. You may need google translate to help you get through the registering process.

Comment: But in order to post, it is necessary to be logged, and it needs a Chinese land telephone. No way to use it.

Comment: No, you can enter your email instead of phone number.

Comment: Ok, I advanced, but now it asks a captcha in Chinese :(

Comment: Did you become a member of that topic by press the "like" button？ By the way, How about using wordpress to post a dedicated blog. Abd then you can either edit the blog or add a comment.

Comment: How about using wordpress to post a dedicated blog. And then you can either edit the blog or add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to create a page in github's wiki and put the link there.

From the script, I get the page via curl, and retrieve the last line that contains the valid link.

- https://github.com/angoca/db2-docker/wiki/db2-link
- https://github.com/angoca/db2-docker/blob/master/install/10.5/expc/download